# What if I want to use embracing operator with `starts_with()`?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rlang, curly-braces

Using the embracing operator eliminates the need to enclose arguments passed to a function in double quotation marks.

But what if I want to use it with `starts_with()`?

```r
# This works.
test <- function(var) {
  mtcars |>
    dplyr::select({{ var }})
}
test(mpg) |> head()
#>                    mpg
#> Mazda RX4         21.0
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0
#> Datsun 710        22.8
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7
#> Valiant           18.1

# But this won't work.
test2 <- function(var) {
  mtcars |>
    dplyr::select(starts_with({{ var }}))
}

test2(m) |> head()
#> Error in `dplyr::select()`:
#> !  オブジェクト 'm' がありません
```

Comment: The first sentence of your question shows that you have a misconception about what `{{…}}` does, because it doesn’t have anything to do with string quoting.

Comment: Sorry for that. I'm new to R. What can I do for improve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
library(dplyr)

test2 <- function(var) {
  x <- deparse(substitute(var))
  mtcars |> select(starts_with(x))
}
test2(m) |> head()
```

Output:

```
                   mpg
Mazda RX4         21.0
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0
Datsun 710        22.8
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4
Hornet Sportabout 18.7
Valiant           18.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though `select` takes unquoted strings and hence works with `test(m)`, this is not the case for `starts_with`, i.e.

```
test2('m')
                     mpg
Mazda RX4           21.0
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0
Datsun 710          22.8
```

Comment: Thanks. yes, in a sample code, that's fine. but in my specific problem, I need to remove the quotation marks. Is that impossible?